# Can the TypeORM save() method also use another key

Tags: typeorm

I´m looking for an upsert solution in TypeORM that doesn´t care about the primary key but uses two other columns for checking, if the dataset can be updated or has to be created.

It looks like the save() method doesn´t support that - is there another way of resolving this besides a "manual" solution?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I"m having this same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68199410